# Keep time in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to keep a timer in my android app. I need the start date of an event, and the end date. Both are triggered with a button, so  i've got those with:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:s");
Date theDate_start = new Date();
```

Is there a method to somehow get the delta date? This would be the easiest way in my opinion.

Comment: See this page, specifically "Difference of Two Dates" about halfway down. http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_java/datesandtimes.html

Comment: A quick tip if you also want to print out the time span is to check out the different `getRelativeTimeSpanString` in [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the Millis of both dates and substract them.